# I've Installed Python 3.7.10, but macOS keeps reporting 2.7.10 when running `python --version`

Tags: python, macos, installation

I'm fairly new to Python, but I assume that I need to point something to the new version of python in order to have my system know there is a new version installed.  I'm on macOS 10.13.6 and installed the newest python with Homebrew's command `brew install python`.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried following [this](https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/) tutorial, but I'm stuck at the portion "ensure PATH....", as it tends to lose me:

```
# Do I have a Python 3 installed?
$ python --version
Python 3.6.4 # Success!
# If you still see 2.7 ensure in PATH /usr/local/bin/ takes precedence over /usr/bin/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `python3 --version`.

Usually you need to add 3 on the end to anything you do with Python in the terminal.

Comment: Actually this worked when I tried it, I knew it was installed on my system because I did this and saw "Python 3.7.0", so I guess my question is, is this new version my default version now?  I don't know anything about Python, but it seems that if I have to specify python3 to get the newest version, that it isn't going to be used by default.

Comment: Again usually if you want to use Python 3 you have to specify with `python3`. `python` by itself usually defaults to 2. Neither are your 'default', though, it just depends on which one you use.

Comment: Could you expand more on how to "use" Python 3?  I'm working on a Python script and need some methods that are only available in Python 3 and they are not working, so I assume my system is still using Python 2.  My Shebang is `#!/usr/bin/python`